# css padding doesn't work on outlook 2010

Tags: javascript, html, css, outlook

My code is like this:

```
  <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                 This is just a paragraph.
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#" style="display: block; padding: 5px 20px; background-color: red">Remove</a>
            </td>
         </tr>
    </table>
```

I want the link element to have padding and to appear like a button and send it by email.
    In browser, it looks good but in outlook desktop, the padding doesn't work!

Comment: no chance..!! can you share a screen shot of the issue?

Comment: I have had screenshot

Comment: https://gist.github.com/webtobesocial/ac9d052595b406d5a5c1

Answer (score 3):

Some outlook doesn't work with padding in inline elements. So you need to add padding in 'td' like below.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
             This is just a paragraph.
        </td>
        <td style="padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom:5px; padding-left:20px; padding-right:20px;"  bgcolor="red">
            <a href="#" style="display: block; ">Remove</a>
        </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```